# Does a discrete set of points in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ define a locally finite collection of hyperplanes?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, convex-analysis

Let $v_{1},v_{2},...$ be a discrete set of non-zero vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. By discrete, I mean that any $v_{i}$ is surrounded by an $\epsilon$-ball not containing any other point $v_{j}$. Equivalently, any compact subset $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ contains only finitely many of the $v_{i}$. (EDIT: These two conditions are not equivalent, and I mean the latter condition. I don't want accumulation points.)

Define affine hyperplanes $H_{i}=\{x \mid \langle v_{i},x \rangle=1\}$. Here $\langle,\rangle$ is the standard inner product.

Is the set of hyperplanes $H_{i}$ locally finite?

Here, locally finite means that given a point $x$ in the union of the hyperplanes, we can find an $\epsilon$-ball around $p$ that intersects only finitely many of the hyperplanes. Equivalently, any compact subset $K$ intersects finitely many of the $H_{i}$. (EDIT: Two conditions needn't be equivalent. I want the latter condition.)

Comment: The two conditions are not equivalent. $\{ \frac1n : n \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$ is discrete in the first sense, but not in the second.

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit. I think I want the latter condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\Bbb R^2$ let $v_k=\langle k,k\rangle$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$; the set $V=\{v_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ is certainly discrete. However, $H_k$ is the line whose equation is $kx+ky=1$, the line of slope $-1$ with $x$- and $y$-intercepts at $\frac1k$. $\{H_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\}$ clusters at every point on the line $y=-x$, so it is not locally finite in $\Bbb R^2$. In particular, the compact set

$$\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\cup\left\{\left\langle\frac1k,\frac1k\right\rangle:k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$$

meets every $H_k$. This set of lines is locally finite in itself, however.

**Added:** Better yet, let $v_k=\langle 2^k,1\rangle$ for $k\in\Bbb N$; $\{v_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ is a discrete subset of $\Bbb R^2$, but $H_k$ is the line $x+2^ky=1$ whose $x$-intercept is $1$ and whose $y$-intercept is $2^{-k}$, so $$\langle 1,0\rangle\in\bigcap_{k\in\Bbb N}H_k\;,$$ and $\{H_k:k\in\Bbb N\}$ isn’t even discrete in itself.